# Open placemark id with an a href from KML layer (Google Maps Api v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a google maps dealer locator. All (55) dealers are saved into a KML file which i load into my google maps:

See: http://paste2.org/p/2248187

I have a search function that finds the closest dealers from your location. The results get printed in a list. Note that this list is outside the Google Maps, in a html sidebar. When I click on the nearest dealer I would like to open the infowindow of that dealer/placemark by using it's ID.

So in short, click on a button outside the google map and an infowindow should open inside the google map.

I have googled for this a lot, but couldn't find anything about opening KML placemark infowindows.

it should be as simple like:
http://paste2.org/p/2248193

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is not available with KmlLayer (at least not now).

Either use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)  or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) or import your KML into FusionTables and use that.

[Example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/AfricaMap1.xml)

[Example using Fusion Tables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

Comment: It's a highly requested feature though. "Star" this issue to both vote for it and track its progress: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3006

Comment: I've found that the geoxml3 solution only seems to link to your KML layer using an index rather than the placemark ID.

Comment: That is the way the example works.  With a third party parser you have the ability to implement that functionality.